# How to allow cross origin in IOS hybrid xamarin app

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, cross-domain

I am developing hybrid mobile app using xamarin. I am facing issue in rendering xod file in IOS webview using PdfTron webviewer. I was also facing same issue in Android app but after setting "AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs=true", it worked fine in Android. So issue was related to cross origin and worked after setting. Now i am looking for same kind of setting in IOS. I tried setting through head  but it is not working. It seems like there must be some setting for this in IOS plist. Please let me know "AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs" equivalent setting in IOS xamarin.

Thanks
Tarlok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get this working by doing the following:

```
var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration { UserContentController = userController };
try
{
    config.Preferences.SetValueForKey(NSObject.FromObject(true), new NSString("allowFileAccessFromFileURLs"));
    config.Preferences.SetValueForKey(NSObject.FromObject(true), new NSString("allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs"));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}

var webView = new WKWebView(Frame, config)
{
    NavigationDelegate = new CustomWKNavigationDelegate(this.Element)
};  
SetNativeControl(webView);
```

The work to allow Cross Domain is done by the `SetValueForKey` this is the only way to do it as there is no API to do this but one thing to remember is the internet says this inst really supported. Hence the `try catch` block

Answer (score 0):

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

As far as i know, you only need to add this to your info.plist

Comment: Hi Greensy, Thanks for reply. I have made the setting but still not able to render xod on webviewer. It seems like IOS is blocking "xod" extension. Is there any way to allow all extension in xamarin info.plist.

Comment: I have reviewed Android code and found setting "webView.Settings.DomStorageEnabled==true" in android. So I think this setting is missing in IOS. Please let me know how to set "DomStorageEnabled" in info.plist.